# while loop runs only in the first iteration of foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

I am trying to loop while inside for loop but the while loop is only iterating in the first iteration of for loop after I only get whatever is outside while loop to work but while stay here my code any help will be great . Thanks

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($obj->conn)>0){             
    foreach ($dateGroup as $value) {
        while($fetchdata=mysqli_fetch_array($selectdata))
            {
                echo 'executing while <br>';
            }
            echo "<b>executing foreach</b><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because after the first iteration you fetched all data and in the second foreach loop iteration there is nothing more to fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - you should reeeeeally try spliting your questions into more understandable fashion - using more sentences, commas, question marks, etc. It could be really hard to understand your problem.

Secondly - you should actually ask a question, not just ask for help with a code that might contain who-knows-what specifics.

In your case the expression inside the while loop parenthesis fetches the data once and there is no more fetching of data afterwards. This is why your while loops executes just once. You should rethink your design here, code proposal, in my opinion are not relevant.

Comment: i am sorry for not putting up the question incorrectly but after hours of head banging i did got my answer thanks for the suggestions i will keep that i ming next time looking for an answer

Comment: No need to apologize, mate! I don't have a problem with, it's rather yours. You should know that the better your explain your problem and question - the more likely it is to get a working solution or a good answer. If I was able to help you with your trouble - then I am happy :)